# How to emulate cellular to wifi (or vice versa) switch on android emulator

Tags: android, android-networking

I am developing a module that downloads something off the internet. I am using AsyncTask to download and am constantly tracking the download process via a flag `isComplete`. The requirement is that whenever the application switches the network from cellular to wifi or vice versa, it should restart the download.
I haev implemented this via a broadcast receiver that listens to intent `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED` and starts redownloading.

```
@Override
onReceive(...){
   if(!isComplete){
        reload();
   }
}
```

I want to test tis on simulator for many reasons such as I dont always have a device that has a cellurla connection and debugging is easy on emulator.

Is there a way I can test the network switch or fire android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE outside the app?

Please advice!

Comment: Why would you want to restart the download?  I understand if the requirement is that it should continue to download the item, but restarting it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: its a multiple step download. Its hard to keep track of the order and completion of all downloads on network switch so its easy and less comple to restart everything . I have presented my problem in a simpler way here

Answer (score 0):

adb shell am broadcast -a Intent_name -c Intent_category -n package_name/class_name

This will send an intent.  I've used it to emulate boot completed in the past to make sure services started on boot.  I'm not sure what parts are optional though (I think package/class name are).